# Detect a re-tab on selected UITabbarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to detect a re-tab on the selected `UITabbarItem`. I'm using a `UIWebview` which url needs to be reset to the homepage again after re-tab on the Home button at index 1 in the UITabbar.

Problem is: I'm using a storyboard and tried to make the `UITabbar` delegate, but it's not working.

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

didLaunchWithOptions:

```
UITabBarController *tabController =
(UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabController.selectedIndex = [defaults integerForKey:kOptionLastTabSelectedKey];
tabController.delegate = self;
```

It's giving the following error:

```
AppDelegate.m:26:36: Use of undeclared identifier 'defaults'
```

Then I need to detect if the tab has been re-tabbed, and if so, the UI webview must been reset to the homepage. So anyone a suggestion how to detect a re-tab on a specific tab? It's at index 1.

I tried:

```
- (void)tabController:(UITabBarController*)tabController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{

    if (tabController.selectedViewController == viewController)
    {
        tabController.selectedIndex =0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set userdefaults and then try like this below:-

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
tabController.selectedIndex = [defaults integerForKey:kOptionLastTabSelectedKey];
```

Comment: Throws another error.. `AppDelegate.m:27:59: Use of undeclared identifier 'kOptionLastTabSelectedKey'`

Comment: oh it means you have not specify your this kOptionLastTabSelectedKey

Comment: For example you have to specify like this on your code #define kOptionLastTabSelectedKey 1