# want to call myMethod() when selecting same tab bar in IOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I Want to call my own method, i.e. `myMethod()` when same tab bar is selected which is already selected.
I had tried to call `didSelectMethod()` but it is not called in my ViewController class.
Please  help me in this, 
Thank you
Jagveer Rana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you own your `tabBarController` instance there you set delegate

```
tabBarController.delegate= self; // It is must to set delegate
```

add the below delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if ([viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)]) {
        [viewController performSelector:@selector(myMethod)];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx alot brother. can u accept my question plaese

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your ViewController class is not the delegate for your UITabBarController, otherwise `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` would be called.

Make sure your delegate is linked up properly.

If that's not the problem, then there are a few other StackOverflow questions asking the same thing:
[Tab bar, reload every time tab is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946511/tab-bar-reload-every-time-tab-is-pressed)
[Detect a re-tab on selected UITabbarItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562973/detect-a-re-tab-on-selected-uitabbaritem)

Comment: thanx alot brother. can u accept my question plaese

Comment: That's not how it works @JagveerSingh - not possible to "accept" a question. You can upvote my answer if it helped you at all though.